# Worklight 6.1 : What is browser compatibility for mobile web app

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, ibm-mobilefirst

We are build mobile web app in worklight version 6.1. Site is working on some browser like firefox , chrome and IE .

We are facing issue with IE it is not working on some IE version , we din't checked on all the browser with different version.

Error which is showing while launching the mobile site is

**appendChild dosn't support line no 6077 wljq.js**

Is there any browser compatibility list on IBM site where we can refer the same.

Answer (score 1):

When you are building a mobile web app (that runs in the mobile browser application) or a web app (for example the Android and iOS environments in Worklight), you are faced with the limitations of each browser's rendering engine capabilities per the browser version (every browser version will have a different set of features, fixes and support for web specifications, etc...).

As such, there is no available compatibility list. There is, however, a minimum - for a browser to support at the least ECMAScript 1.8.1 in order to be able to run the Worklight JS framework, and this is supported in all browsers by now, mobile or desktop.

If you are facing issues with a specific browser or browser version, you simply need to overcome it like you would in any web development (app or website). You can for example use a [Polyfill](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill) to add missing functionality or devise other alternatives.

Basically, Worklight does not limit you to specific browsers or browser versions for your applications.

As the question is written in a pretty generalized manner and you do not explain the actual issue you are facing and whether it is actually related to Worklight or not, that is the best I can write at this time.

Comment: i have updated my question . Please check and revert.

Comment: You updated with the error, please also mention the Explorer version and anything else relevant.

Comment: Also provide context to your question - where does it fail for you, is it a specific function in your app or the entire app?

Comment: I clearly mentioned my question that at the time of launch it fails.

Comment: And the version of IE? WP8? Desktop? Please add more information.